# What happened to the Fokker 100 revival project?

Tags: aircraft-design, fokker-100

What happened to the Fokker 100 revival project by NG Aircraft?

They wanted to build a better Fokker 100 called the Fokker 120NG/Fokker 130 in 2010-2014 which originally should be completed this year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NG Aircraft [still exists](https://www.ngaircraft.com/), or at least, they still have a website. The big roadblock is [financing the development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands_Aircraft_Company) of the aircraft. I did a search in Dutch government records: the most recent mention is in [2016](https://www.tweedekamer.nl/kamerstukken/detail?id=2016Z15645&did=2016D32469), indicating that at that time sufficient funding has not been found yet to start development in earnest.

LinkedIn shows [11 employees](https://www.linkedin.com/company/netherlands-aircraft-company).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and your research